# Passing values inbetween functions within an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am making a mini calendar. I am trying to pass the appropriate values into the view section of the object.  But I keep on getting undefined in the view section. What am I doing wrong?

```
var date = {  

  monthsArray: ["January", "February","March","April","May","June","July","August", "September", "October", "November","December" ],
  init: function() {
    var fullDate = new Date();
    this.dateParsed(fullDate);
    this.view();
  },
  stringifyMonth: function(monthNumber) {
    var monthName = this.monthsArray[monthNumber]
    return monthName
  },
  dateParsed: function(fullDate){
   var fullDate = new Date();
   var monthNumber = fullDate.getMonth();
   var dayNumber = fullDate.getDate();
   var calanderYear = fullDate.getFullYear();
   this.stringifyMonth(monthNumber)
   return calanderYear
  },
  view: function(monthName){

    console.log(this.stringifyMonth())   ///  undefined 


  }

}.init()
```

Comment: Return `this` from `init`?

Comment: @torazaburo That won't make any difference in this case as the `date` object is not used from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stringifyMonth expects a parameter, but you are not passing one.
thus, *null* is passed as a parameter, and then you are trying to access this.monthsArray[null], which is undefined.

Try passing a parameter like 1 and you will see that it print February.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. Pass current month to the `view` function. You can get the month from date object using `getMonth()`
2. Pass the same month to the `stringifyMonth` from `view`

*See the highlighted changes and comments*

```js
var date = {

  monthsArray: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  init: function() {
    var fullDate = new Date();
    this.dateParsed(fullDate);

    
    // Get the current month from date object and pass to the view()
    this.view(fullDate.getMonth()); // <-----
  },
  stringifyMonth: function(monthNumber) {
    var monthName = this.monthsArray[monthNumber]
    return monthName
  },
  dateParsed: function(fullDate) {
    var fullDate = new Date();
    var monthNumber = fullDate.getMonth();
    var dayNumber = fullDate.getDate();
    var calanderYear = fullDate.getFullYear();
    this.stringifyMonth(monthNumber)
    return calanderYear
  },
  view: function(monthName) {
    
    // Pass the monthName to the stringifyMonth()
    console.log(this.stringifyMonth(monthName)); // <-----
  }
}.init();
```

Comment: Can you explain why it didn't work the way I had it? Did it have to do with scope?

Comment: @YoniMessing Since you haven't passed parameters, their value is `undefined` so the error is thrown. If you don't want to pass them as parameter and access directly you need to use `this.varName`